# Salt and hashing, why not use username?

Tags: encryption, hash, cryptography, salt, password-encryption

I must confess to being largely ignorant on most of the high-tech security issues relevant for web applications, but there is one thing I at least thought I could ask because it is a direct question with (hopefully) a concrete answer.

Take this website: http://www.15seconds.com/issue/000217.htm

It shows a bit down that they store the salt value in the table, I understand the principles and the math behind *using* a salt, but I'm wondering this:

Why did they not just use the username as a salt value instead of generating one?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Because user names have lower entropy than a random salt, so they spread your hashes around less than a proper salt does.

Not that the example on that page is very spectacular anyway.  I always just generate a GUID and use that.

I suspect it's all down in the noise as far as real-life security is concern, and even quite small amounts of per-user salt make a big difference to security, with very small improvements as the salt gets more complex.

Comment: Thanks, that matches my original thoughts on the subject.

Comment: Another consideration: wouldn't using the username as part of the hash make it impossible for admins to change the user's username without either knowing the user's password or changing it? I just encountered this issue in a system I inherited where emails are used as usernames...the hash includes a random salt string, but it because it also includes the email address, it leads to the above-mentioned problem with changing the email.

Comment: @MattBrowne: Very good point! One practical thought though: If the user attempts to change his email himself, usually he should have to enter the password to confirm the change. You could first verify the password (with the old email/username), and then in a single transaction change email address, as well as calculate the new password hash from the entered password. Not that I recommend using username/email as salt, just a thought concerning this problem. But email/username changes without entering the password (eg. an admin wanting to change it for someone) obviously still won't be possible.

Comment: When you're first building a system, it's impossible to predict all the future requirements, and one of them may be for admins to change usernames even if it at first seems sufficient that users can change their own usernames.

Comment: And changing your password hashing mechanism is a real pain because it means all the users have to change their passwords.

Answer (score 43):

The point of the salt is to be unique. The salt is meant to prevent attack cost sharing, i.e. an attacker trying to attack two hashed passwords for less than the twice the cost of attacking one.

One solution to ensure uniqueness is to generate a random salt in a wide enough space. Therefore, getting twice the same salt for two distinct password instances is sufficiently improbable that it will not happen in practice.

The user name is *not* adequately unique:

- The user name does not change when the user changes his password. An attacker seeing the old hashed password and the new hashed password may attack both at a cost less than twice the cost of attacking one.
- At a given time, user names are unique system-wide, not world-wide. There are many "bob"s out there (in a Unix system, consider "root"). Using the user name may allow an attacker to attack several systems simultaneously.

Salt entropy is not really important, except in so much as it ensures uniqueness in a random generation setting.

Comment: I often see the bit about new+old passwords, but I'm unclear why it's useful to people to attack an old password.   I could *tell* you that the old password I was using yesterday was 'letmein', but it wouldn't help you today.

Comment: It makes more sense in the context of password-based encryption, e.g. as protecting a Zip archive. Also, users tend to reuse passwords, hence an old password is often a future password as well (or a password used by the same individual in another system).

Comment: Well, then I don't see a problem in using something like hash(domain + username + password) to make it globally and locally unique. The argument with the old password and the changing of username remains valid, though.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
Salt = CryptoHash( CryptoHash(SubmittedEmailOrUsername) . CryptoHash(SubmittedPasswd) ) ?
```

That would seemingly

1. have the advantage of not needing to store the salt as it can be dynamically calculated,
2. while still having good entropy (hash-based instead of plaintext), and
3. provides a salt that's as long as a cryptographic hash eg 128-512 bits?

One problem would be if the system allowed two user to have the username and password (wouldnt happen with email addr though), but are there any other problems with this scheme?

Comment: This is circular: the salt is used to obtain "CryptoHash(Passwd)".

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, which is "why don't we use usernames?", not "what might we do to use usernames better?".

Comment: <pre>Davis, can you please elaborate on the circularity? Here is Registering + Lookup, it seems ok?<br/>

For registration/new account, new user submits their Email & Password<br/>
System calculates Salt=Hash( Hash(Email) . Hash(passwd) )<br/>
System can now calculate StoredPassword for that Email = Hash(Salt . Email . Passwd)<br/>
<br/>
For Login, user enters Email & Password<br/>
System calculates Salt=Hash( Hash(Email) . Hash(Passwd) )<br/>
System looks up StoredPassword for Email<br/>
System compares StoredPassword with Hash(Salt . Email . Passwd)<br/>

Comment: apologies for formatting :( it wont let me add linebreaks (it said use "<br/>" but seemingly thats not in the Reply subset), and then my 5 mins edit time expired. Reading the formatting/comment help pages now