# Store one big Hash instead of User/Pass in DB

Tags: sql, database, security, hash

Normally a password is stored with a one-way algorithm, so that it makes hard to discover the plain text from it.
But I've been thinking: What if I store a SHA512 of both username and password melted together (A+B=SHA512), instead of the username and the password hash separately.
Is this method secure?

EDIT: In my opinion the Username 'salt' the password, so there will be no equal hash two times...

Comment: It's not a good idea to use username as salt, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5567965/1615903)

Answer (score 2):

(1) You should be using something like bcrypt, scrypt, or pbkdf2 instead of something like SHAwhatever for password processing.  Google this.

(2) How would you deal with forgotten password scenario?

(3) See my blog, particularly the section on "A simple example: protecting email address": https://littlemaninmyhead.wordpress.com/2015/09/08/a-retrospective-on-ashely-madison-and-the-value-of-threat-modeling/

Comment: A forgotten password should not be recovered in plain text.

Comment: @Fusseldieb, May I recommend that you read the blog again, because you clearly did not get it.  The forgotten password functionality in the blog is about "password resets", not about retrieving passwords, which is not possible by this design.

Answer (score 0):

Sure that would work.  But would you ever want to retrieve a list of user names?

In the authentication implementations I have written, I use the username as part of the salt.  That combined with a sitewide salt plus a bit of constant salt ends up creating around 120 bits of salt per username.